# Capitalisation of "possible" in duplicate comment

Tags: feature-request

There's nothing much to this question, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

> When a question is flagged as a duplicate, a comment of the form "possible duplicate of . . ." is posted. Why isn't it "Possible duplicate of . . ."?

Comment: Since we're nitpicking, the start of your sentence doesn't seem quite grammatical! :-) How about just rewrite this as a feature request? I'm sure there's no intention.

Comment: Good point. How do I make a feature request?

Comment: François did it for you; just use the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag.